# Android Studio : Gradle failed to resolve Dependencies

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I recently migrated an eclipse project to androidStudio. But while building AS failed to resolve the dependencies. Initially I thought it might be the proxy problem as I am in the restricted network, So I added the proxy settings resulting nothing.
So I tried gradlew in terminal and the output of is as below :

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.2.
>   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom'.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom'.
>   This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server

So I tried reaching "https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/2.3.2/gradle-2.3.2.pom" from my browser and it browser downloaded file successfully. That means network if fine.

So why AS studio is failing to solve dependencies?
Is there something wrong with the gradle version?
How do I decide which gradle version suits my Project?

Appreciate your responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

First :

```
repositories {
    jcenter({url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"})
}
```

If that does not work.Gradle to manually sync proxy

```
gradlew -Dhttps.proxyHost=127.0.0.1 -Dhttps.proxyPort=8580
```

Comment: what is the default url for jcenter the. like jcenter()

Comment: Force use this url.